# Redirect 301 appending / to urls with #

Tags: redirect, apache2

I moved some content on my server from `/foo/` to a `<div id="foo">` on my main page.
I want to redirect like so:

`example.com/foo/` → `example.com/#foo`

So I wrote this Redirect statement in `.htaccess` -

```
Redirect 301 "/foo/" "/#foo"
```

However, this really does:

`example.com/foo/` → `example.com/#foo/`

<sup><sup>*Note the trailing slash...*</sup></sup>

Which is not what I want.

I also tried,

```
Redirect 301 "/foo/" "http://example.com/#foo"
```

Thanks <3

Comment: Are you sure that your app framework isn't doing it? It doesn't appear that Apache is doing so.

Comment: I doubt it; Google cloud VM with stock (AFAIK) Apache2.

Comment: You haven't asked Apache for a trailing slash. Your app framework is the prime suspect here. You need to confirm it.